# Angular2: package not found

Tags: angular

I installed package 'angular2-web-worker' using npm to my project, but i get 404 (not found) error when try to use it.

package.json:

```
      "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "^4.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.2.3",
    "@angular/core": "^4.2.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.2.3",
    "@angular/http": "^4.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^4.2.3",
    "@angular/router": "^4.2.3",
    "@angular/upgrade": "^2.4.10",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.52",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.66",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.78",
    "angular-2-local-storage": "^1.0.1",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "^0.2.5",
    "angular2-web-worker": "0.0.6",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "browserify": "^14.5.0",
    "concurrently": "^3.4.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "gulp-load-plugins": "^1.5.0",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "lite-server": "^2.3.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "ng2-bs3-modal": "^0.10.4",
    "primeng": "^4.0.0-rc.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.10",
    "rollup-plugin-node-resolve": "^2.1.1",
    "rollup-plugin-uglify": "^1.0.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "shim": "^0.6.0",
    "systemjs": "0.19.40",
    "typescript": "^2.4.0",
    "zingchart": "^2.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "browserify": "^14.5.0",
    "concurrently": "^3.1.0",
    "del": "^2.2.2",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-gzip": "^1.4.0",
    "gulp-load-plugins": "^1.3.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-task-listing": "^1.0.1",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.7",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "rollup": "^0.36.1",
    "rollup-plugin-commonjs": "^5.0.4",
    "rollup-plugin-node-resolve": "^2.0.0",
    "rollup-plugin-uglify": "^1.0.1",
    "typescript": "^2.0.10",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.46",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.36",
    "@types/selenium-webdriver": "2.53.33"
  }
```

systen-config.js

```
System.config({
paths: {
    // paths serve as alias
    'npm:': 'node_modules/'
},
// map tells the System loader where to look for things
map: {
    // our app is within the app folder
    'app': 'dist/app',
    'main': 'dist/app/main.js',
    // angular bundles
    '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
    '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
    '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
    '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
    '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
    '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
    '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
    '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
    '@angular/upgrade': 'npm:@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade.umd.js',
    '@angular/animations': 'npm:@angular/animations/bundles/animations.umd.js',
    '@angular/animations/browser': 'npm:@angular/animations/bundles/animations-browser.umd.js',
    '@angular/platform-browser/animations': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser-animations.umd.js',  

    // other libraries
    'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
    'ng2-bs3-modal': 'npm:ng2-bs3-modal',
    'angular2-web-worker': 'npm:angular2-web-worker/dist',
    'angular-2-local-storage': 'npm:angular-2-local-storage/dist',
    'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js',
    'lodash': 'npm:lodash',
    'primeng': 'npm:primeng',
},
// packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
packages: {
    'app': { main: './main.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'angular-2-local-storage': { main: './index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'angular2-datatable': { main: './index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'api': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'rxjs': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'ng2-bs3-modal': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'lodash': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'primeng': { defaultExtension: 'js' }
}
```

});

inside my service:

```
import { WebWorkerService } from 'angular2-web-worker';
constructor(localStorage: LocalStorageService, private _webWorkerService: WebWorkerService){
}
```

I get the error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:8000/node_modules/angular2-web-worker/dist
I tried also:
import { WebWorkerService } from 'angular2-web-worker/web-worker.service';
but it didn't worked. What is the problem? 
thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36628242/angular-2-npm-install-package-not-working

Comment: system-config is not enough ? i dont have SystemJS